# How to change the background color of Popup MenuButton bullet window?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to change the background color of Popup Menu Button window. What should I do? I hope I can get your help. Thank you.When I change the color of container, some corners cannot change the color.

```
 new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          new PopupMenuButton(
            offset: const Offset(0.0, 60.0),
            icon: new Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
                  new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                      value: '选项一的值',
                      child: new Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: new Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Image.asset(defaultAvatar,
                                      width: 30.0, height: 30.0),
                                  new Text('发起群聊')
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ))),
                  new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                      value: '选项一的值',
                      child: new Container(
                          child: new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Image.asset(defaultAvatar,
                                  width: 30.0, height: 30.0),
                              new Text('添加朋友')
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ))),
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That background color is based on the `Theme` , so you can change the color wrapping your `PopMenuButton` inside `Theme` and change the `cardColor`.

```
          Theme(
                data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                  cardColor: Colors.red,
                ),
                child: new PopupMenuButton(
                       ...
```

Comment: cardColor: has not worked for me , so i did it with canvasColor:

Comment: I needed to change the active item's **_highlight color_**, so in my case, I used `highlightColor`.

Answer (score 8):

It's kinda ugly, but hey:

```
PopupMenuButton<String>(
   onSelected: (selected) {},
   icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: Colors.white,),
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
      ...
   },
),
```

Answer (score 3):

By default PopupMenuButton has a tint color.

> surfaceTintColor = popupMenuTheme.shadowColor

so we also need to set its color, to make it work.

```
PopupMenuButton(
  color: Colors.red,
  surfaceTintColor: Colors.red,
  child: ...
),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just change the background color using `PopupMenuButton( color: Colors.red, ...)` without having to wrap it in a new theme.

Answer (score 1):

```
Center(
      child: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          cardColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        child: PopupMenuButton(
          child: Text("Show Popup Menu"),
          itemBuilder: (context) => [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text("InduceSmile.com"),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text("Flutter.io"),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text("Google.com"),
                ),
              ],
        ),
      ),
```

This is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Flutter 3.10, it works like this:

```
PopupMenuButton(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: ...
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{Color? color}
Type: Color?
```

If provided, the background color used for the menu.

If this property is null, then [PopupMenuThemeData.color] is used. If [PopupMenuThemeData.color] is also null, then Theme.of(context).cardColor is used.

```
PopupMenuButton(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: ...
),
```