# How to change the background color of PopupMenuItem under the showMenu?

Tags: dart, flutter

I don't use PopupMenuButton.

Because in my case, showMenu would be more appropriate.

```
onLongPress: () => _onRoomLongPressed(context, _tappedPosition, model, room),
```

```
void _onRoomLongPressed(BuildContext context, Offset tappedPosition,
    RoomsModel model, Room room) {
  final RenderBox overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject();

  showMenu(
    context: context,
    position: RelativeRect.fromRect(
        tappedPosition & Size.zero, Offset.zero & overlay.size),
    items: [
      PopupMenuItem(
        value: 'delete',
        child: Text('delete'),
      ),
    ],
  ).then((String value) {
    switch (value) {
      case 'delete':
        model.remove(room);
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

Don't change the theme of `MaterialApp()`.

I expect that the background color of `PopupMenuItem` to be white and the `Text` color black.

Comment: you can't using showMenu, you will have to use a popmenubutton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662200/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-popup-menubutton-bullet-window/53663708#53663708

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your widget that opens up the menu in a `Builder` and have `Theme` as the parent of this `Builder`. Here is the code that will get you going.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      cardColor: Colors.white,
      textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(bodyColor: Colors.black),
    ),
    child: Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Show menu"),
          onPressed: () {
            showMenu(
              context: context,
              position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0, 100, 0, 0),
              items: [
                PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Item 0"), value: 0),
                PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Item 1"), value: 1),
                PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Item 2"), value: 2),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: I just updated my post.You can check it. In my case, showMenu would be more appropriate.

Comment: @QiminQiu I have updated the code, have a look on it. It now uses `showMenu()`.

Comment: your answer woked. Today I havd a similar problem when I used showModalBottomSheet. And it is also worked with your method. Could you tell me why that Theme as the parent of Builder worked? I've try Theme inside of showModalBottomSheet, but it is not working.

Comment: You need to use `Builder` so that it can introduce new `context` for the various widgets like `PopupMenuItem`, `BottomSheet`, etc.