# How to make a popup Menu Button like Floating Action Button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to have a Button at the appBar that shows me three further buttons when I click on it like a Floating Action with FAB, but which is positioned at the appBar.

like on the top right corner
 [image]

I tried a lot of options like Floating Action buttons, IconButtons, and PopupMenuButton.

This is my best solution with a PopupMenuButton:

```js
PopupMenuButton<Choice>(
           
            icon: Icon(
                MyIcon.edit,
               
                size: 35, color: Colors.white, 
              ),
            //  child: IconButton( icon: Icon(
            //     MyIcon.edit,
            //     // color: Colors.white,
            //     size: 35, color: Colors.white, 
            //   ),onPressed: _buildLayoutContainer,
            //  ),
              elevation: 0,
              onSelected: choiceAction,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                return choices.map((Choice choice) {
                  if (choice.text == null) {
                    return PopupMenuItem<Choice>(
                      value: choice,
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 50,
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return PopupMenuItem<Choice>(
    
                    
                      value: choice,
                      child: Row(
                       mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                         
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 103,
                          ),
                          choice.text,
                          SizedBox(
                            width: choice.width,
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              IconButton(
                                icon: choice.icon,
                                onPressed: () => _selectTransaction(context),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: choice.height,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                         
                        ],
                        
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }).toList();
              }),
```

I did not find a way to align the icons vertically with the edit button on the top right corner and I could not do a backdrop with an elevation to focus at the three icons like for example in a Drawer Widget or like in picture 1.
And this is how it looks:
[image]

Is there a more elegant way to make this kind of button, especially solving these two issues with the Backdrop and aligning?

I would love to hear some advice :)

Comment: Is it possible to change the position itembuilder card to sollte the aligning issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PopupMenuButton` support `offset`, you can use `offset` to adjust display position 
You can reference https://medium.com/flutteropen/widgets-14-popupmenubutton-1f1437bbdce2

code snippet

```
PopupMenuButton<Choice>(
        offset: Offset(100, 100), 
        icon: Icon(
```

example from reference document

```
Widget _offsetPopup() => PopupMenuButton<int>(
          itemBuilder: (context) => [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: 1,
                  child: Text(
                    "Flutter Open",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: TEXT_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: 2,
                  child: Text(
                    "Flutter Tutorial",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: TEXT_BLACK, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
          icon: Icon(Icons.library_add),
          offset: Offset(0, 100),
        );
```

Comment: Thank you ^^. You solved the aligning issue. Do you know how to add a backdrop like on a drawer?

Comment: Could you post add a backdrop like on a drawer to another question and provide image you expected. thanks.

Comment: do you mean background color, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662200/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-popup-menubutton-bullet-window

Comment: I want it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60236867/how-to-add-a-backdrop-shadow-to-the-rest-of-the-screen-when-i-click-at-my-pupupm. Do you understand my problem?